# How come data is not coming from my hiera yaml file?

Tags: hiera, puppet-enterprise

I am using Puppet Enterprise 3.7.2 and on one of my nodes I create the file:

```
[root@vii-osc4-mgmt-001 ~]# cat /etc/profile.d/POD_prefix.sh 
export FACTER_pod_prefix=vii-osc4
```

Then I rebooted that node and logged back in and verified that 
the FACTER_pod_prefix gets set and facter pod_prefix outputs the
expected value.

```
[root@vii-osc4-mgmt-001 ~]# env | grep FACTER_pod_prefix
FACTER_pod_prefix=vii-osc4
[root@vii-osc4-mgmt-001 ~]# facter pod_prefix
vii-osc4
```

On my PE 3.7 Puppet master I created the file /var/lib/hiera/vii-osc4.yaml.
I created the /var/lib/hiera/vii-osc4.yaml from the /var/lib/hiera/defaults.yaml
file that I had been using like so:

```
# cp /var/lib/hiera/defaults.yaml /var/lib/hiera/vii-osc4.yaml
```

This file has a bunch of class parameter values. For example there is this
line in the file:

```
controller_vip_name: vii-osc4.example.com
```

Then I changed my hiera.yaml file to look like this:

```
[root@osc4-ppt-001 ~]# cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "%{pod_prefix}"
  - defaults
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /var/lib/hiera on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\hiera\var on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir:
```

Then I restarted my pe-httpd service like so (RHEL7):

```
# systemctl restart pe-httpd
```

Then I make a small change to the /var/lib/hiera/vii-osc4.yaml for example
I change the line ...

```
controller_vip_name: vii-osc4.example.com
```

... to ...

```
controller_vip_name: VII-osc4.example.com
```

But when I run `puppet agent -t --noop` on my node, vii-osc4-mgmt-001, I do not see the change
that I expected to see.  If I make the change in the /var/lib/hiera/defaults.yaml and then
run `puppet agent -t --noop` on my node I do see the expected changes.  What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: using `/etc/facter/facts.d` method of setting custom facts.

I looked into using `/etc/facter/facts.d` for what I am trying to do.  What I am trying to do is set a custom fact "pod_prefix".  I want to use this fact in my hiera.yaml like so ...

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::pod_prefix}"
  - defaults
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /var/lib/hiera on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\hiera\var on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir:
```

... so that nodes that have pod_prefix set to `vii-osc4` will obtain their class parameters from the file `/var/lib/hiera/vii-osc4/yaml` and host that `pod_prefix` set to `ix-xyz` will get their class params from `/var/lib/hiera/ix-xyz.yaml`.  I do not see how creating the file  `/etc/facter/facts.d/pod_prefix.txt` on my puppet master that contains something like this ...

```
# cat pod_prefix.txt 
pod_prefix=vii-osc4
```

... could possibly be a solution to my problem.  I guess I must be misunderstanding something here.  Can someone help?

UPDATE 2.

The /etc/facter/facts.d/pod_prefix.txt file goes on my nodes.
I think my biggest problem is that just execute `systemctl restart pe-httpd` was not sufficient and things didn't start working until I did a full reboot of my puppet master.  I need to go look at the docs and figure out what is the correct way to restart the "puppet master".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very approach of managing custom facts through environment variables is quite brittle. In this case, I suspect it does not work because you changed the environment of **login shells** via `/etc/profile.d`. System services don't run in such shells, though.

A clean approach would be to define your fact value in `/etc/facter/facts.d` instead.

Comment: Yes you are 2nd person to suggest that.  I am confused though.  Where do I create my /etc/facter/facts.d files, on the puppet master or on the node?  Do you think setting the FACTER_pod_prefix env var would work if I put a file /etc/sysconfig/pe-puppet on the node at set env var in that file?

Comment: Hi Felix, I updated my question with my facts.d attempt.  Could you please take a look :)

Comment: Static fact values can be put in a `facts.d` directory in [any module](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.4/custom_facts.html#fact-locations). If you need things to be more dynamic, you will have to manage the files using plain old `file` resources like everything else.